# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.disthub2.impl.client.SessionConfig

Tags: java, maven, ibm-mq, spring-jms

We are using Websphere MQ 7.5 as a messaging solution, using Spring JMS (v4.0.1) we have written a sender class to send some sample messages to this MQ, Now when the spring context is getting initialized it is throwing below **ClassNotFoundException** exception

```
    SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1021)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5162)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory.class$(WMQFactoryFactory.java:132)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory.setupDistHubTracing(WMQFactoryFactory.java:360)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory.<init>(WMQFactoryFactory.java:330)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQFactoryFactory.java:182)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQComponent.getFactoryInstance(WMQComponent.java:138)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactoryImpl.java:152)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.setProviderFactory(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:176)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.<init>(MQConnectionFactory.java:285)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.<init>(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.disthub2.impl.client.SessionConfig
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    ... 38 more
```

Below is my entry in spring xml

```
<!-- JMS configuration for Server to send the messages.  -->
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory"> 
    <property name="hostName" value="${jms.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${jms.port}" />
    <property name="queueManager" value="${jms.queueManager}" />
    <property name="transportType" value="${jms.transportType}" />      
</bean>

<bean id="cachedConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="20"/>
</bean>

 <bean id="senderJMSTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"> 
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachedConnectionFactory"/> 
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="false" /> 
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="senderQueue"/>
</bean>  
<bean id="senderQueue" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue"> 
    <constructor-arg value="${jms.queueName}" /> 
</bean> 
<bean id="jmsSender" class="com.wdpr.payment.util.JMSMessageProducer"> 
    <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="senderJMSTemplate"/>   
</bean>

<!-- JMS Configuration ends -->
```

My Maven entries

Note: This mq jars have been downloaded to our internal maven repo, and we are accessing from there

```
<!-- Websphere MQ dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mq</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mqjms</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mqjms</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mq.jmqi</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.jmqi</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I tried searching on google but did not find any pointers as to from where and which jar needs to be added to eliminate this error.

Comment: No jars need to be added, but maybe some need to be removed / changed. Please do not confuse NoClassDefFoundError with ClassNotFound!

Comment: @John it is throwing ClassNotFoundException... if you go at the end of stack trace you will notice

Comment: I'm pretty confident it is a classloader issue. Easy way to check is by using mavens dependency tree and finding duplicate classes in the same context. Usually mixed versions of the same dependency. I might be dead wrong also.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you are missing below jar that contains sessionconfig

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.ibm.disthub2.dhbcore</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```